# How to change the color of a UIlabel in the next ViewController, to the selected color in the current ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have two view controllers. In the first one i have label and 4 buttons representing a color, and a button called next. I want to accomplish that when a user selects a color in the first view controller and clicks next, that the label in my next viewController will automatically have that color.

This is what i have so far but i can't make it work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var backGroundColor = UIColor()

@IBOutlet var face: UILabel!


@IBAction func red(sender: AnyObject) {

    face.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

@IBAction func green(sender: AnyObject) {

    face.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

}

@IBAction func blue(sender: AnyObject) {

    face.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

}

@IBAction func yellow(sender: AnyObject) {

    face.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

}

@IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {


    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("face") as! Face2

     vc.newFace.backgroundColor =  self.face.backgroundColor

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

```
// My Face2 class:
import UIKit

class Face2: UIViewController {

    var backGroundColor = UIColor()


    @IBOutlet var newFace: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//    var  vc = ViewController()
        self.newFace.backgroundColor = backGroundColor


    }

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `vc2`?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

You are making a common design mistake.

Don't try to manipulate the second view controller's views directly. That's bad design, and often doesn't work.

Instead add a property/properties to your Face2 class.

In this case, a `backgroundColor` property is probably all you need.

Set that property in your `next` function, and then in your Face2 class's viewDidLoad method, use the color to set the background color of whatever views need to use the custom color. If you decide later that the set of views that need to change color is different, you can change the code for your Face2 class and the first view controller doesn't need to change at all.

You also need to get rid of vc2. That makes no sense. You create a new Face2 view controller `vc` with a call to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. That's the one you should be configuring. The one you create in vc2 is never used for anything. It will get deallocated as soon as you exit the `next()` function.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for your answer and for welcoming me. I am still learning Swift and it's my intention to learn avoiding bad design. I edited my code above to show what i have changed according to your advise. unfortunately, i'm still doing something wrong because it crashes while unwrapping? Probably i'm doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: It looks to me like you added a `backgroundColor` property to your Face2 class, but in the sending view controller you still have code that tries to set the color on the `newFace` outlet directly. Don't do that. Use the line `vc.backgroundColor =  self.face.backgroundColor` instead.

Comment: Hi Dunca, you're awesome, thanks for helping. It solved my problem. I uprooted your answer, but because i'm new, i apparently can't. Thanks again!

Comment: You can't up-vote until you have at least 15 rep, but if my answer solved your problem you should accept it. That tells other people that this answer solves the problem, which makes the thread more useful to others. Accepting the earliest/best correct answer is an important part of asking questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to set a nsstring (string that you set when you press the color button) property to second view controller and in the second view controller view did load make a switch based on the passed string to set the background color